# Angular async and event unexpectedly re-evaluating Observable

Tags: angular, events, asynchronous, observable

My component utilises hot BehaviorSubject to observe a collection retrieved via http, but for simplicity I'll just create a basic BehaviorSubject driven list.

[snip]

**This works exactly as expected.**

Let's do something with the result, add an event to the list items (click, or mouseover etc.)

```
 <li  
     *ngFor="let label of labels | async"
     (mouseover)="listMouseover()"
     >

      <span>{{convertString(label.title)}}</span>

  </li>
```

...

```
convertString(s:string) {

    console.log("evaluating string", s);
    return s + "!"; 

}
```

What you'll observe(!) is that the getter for the Observable is now hit every time any event is triggered, and (worse) the entire list is rebuilt. If this were expensive, this could be a problem, especially for something like mouseover.

[Edit - the async part is not relevant, happens with any list]

**How do you mitigate this behavior, especially if reflow is expensive?**

Thanks.  [Plunkr here](https://embed.plnkr.co/DUYkBVU20utuDoZdDPKq/).

Comment: Yes it is expected behavior. Angular executes template expressions after every change detection cycle.

Comment: Thank you I have edited the question to reflect the fact that async is not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

On your `*ngFor` use a `trackBy`.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html (ctrl+F `trackBy`).

This will allow you to specify an identifier so that Angular won't tear down and recreate the DOM elements if the identifier is still present.

For the observable issue, you could create a simple cache so that it won't incur an expensive operation when the event is fired.

One such example is here:

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/caching-with-rxjs-observables-in-angular-2.0